# Induction proof on a DFA

Tags: induction, computer-science, automata

The following DFA recognizes the language containing either the substring $101$ or $010$. I need to prove this by using induction.

[image]

So far, I have managed to split each state up as follows:

- $q_0$: Nothing has been input yet.
- $q_1$: The last letter was a $1$ and the last two characters were not $01$.
- $q_2$: The last letter was a $0$ with the letter before that a $1$.
- $q_3$: The last letter was a $0$ and the last two characters were not $10$.
- $q_4$: The last letter was a $1$ with the letter before that a $0$.
- $q_5$: At least one of the two substrings has been seen.

Induction basis: The empty string does not have either of the substrings, so is correctly rejected in $q0$.

But I am not too sure on how to proceed after this. I do not know how I should split the string up to prove that the $DFA$ is accurate.

If anyone knows how I should proceed with this, I would love some help!

Comment: You write "either the substring 101 or 010", but the automaton recognizes even strings with both substrings. Note that 'either' means 'exclusive or' in many formal settings.

Answer (score 1):

You should induct on the length of the input string!

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language recognized by this DFA, and write $x \sqsubseteq y$ for $x$ is a substring of $y$.

If the input ($x$) has length 0, 1, or 2, then:

- $x \not \in \mathcal{L}$
- $101, 010 \not \sqsubseteq x$

Now if the input has length 3:

$
x \in \mathcal{L} \iff 
x = 101 \text{ or } 010 \iff 
101 \text{ or } 010 \sqsubseteq x
$

Now, inductively, say $x \in \mathcal{L} \iff 101 \text{ or } 010 \sqsubseteq x$.
What can we say about $x0$ and $x1$? Here we should use the cases that you've mentioned! What we do with $x0$ and $x1$ will depend on the last few digits of the string.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for the response! I see what you are saying but could you perhaps give an example with one of the cases to explain how exactly this proof should be done? For instance, with $q4$ would the proof be something like since the previous string is $01$, adding a $0$ would lead to an accept state in $q5$ since that is a valid substring whereas with a $1$ we have to restart and go to $q1$ to look for the other substring which begins with a $1$ ($101$)? Thank you again!

Comment: Consider a string $x$ of length $n \ge 3$. If $x$ contains the substrings then the DFA will also accept $x0$ and $x1$. If $x$ does not contain the substrings, the last 3 digits of $x$ must be one of the following: 000, 001, 011, 100, 110, 111. Now, what do you think happens when you add a 0 or 1 to each of these cases?

Comment: @user137481 I see. So say I have a string where the last $3$ digits are $000$, which means that it has stopped in state $q3$ by the induction hypothesis.. By induction, if a $0$ is added it will continue to be in $q3$ as its last input was $0$ and the last two inputs were not $10$. Also,  by induction, if a $1$ is added, the last two letters will be $01$ which correctly leads it to be in $q4$. Is this the correct way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes, adding a 0 to 001 will give you the substring 010. Adding a 1 to 110 will give you the substring 101. For the other cases, it does not matter whether you add a 0 or a 1. You won't get the substrings.